# Dictionary shows wrong language (British English instead of American English)

Tags: mojave, language, dictionary

Under macOS 10.14.4, I've enabled the following dictionaries:

[image]

Yet, when I hid <kbd>⌃⌘D</kbd>, I get the results as follows:

[image]

I would expect the results to show *only* American English dictionaries, and not British English.

Comment: I'm happy with British English :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug that appears when you're switching languages. I know I had switched from British to American English at some point before.

What you have to do is:

- Open *Dictionary.app*
- Go to *Preferences*
- Uncheck all dictionaries
- Enable the ones that you need

Now the order is correct, and the British dictionary entries are gone from the results.